# carousel Menu load only after refresh and not working in IE

Tags: javascript, asp.net, mootools, carousel

I am populating a carousel menu dynamically. For this i have a web-method which returns the inner html of carousel div in string format.

On page load i have called a java-script from server side. this javascript called the web method and on success load the inner html of div.

Problem is that, it is working when i refresh the page. not in first load. Also it is not working on IE. Yet it is working on my local ISS (only in Chrome).

Below is the java-script

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
function HandleIT() {

    var a = document.getElementById("carousel");
    PageMethods.GetCarousel(onSucess, onError);
    debugger;
    function onSucess(result) {
        debugger;
        document.getElementById("carousel").innerHTML = result;
    }
    function onError(result) {
        alert('Something wrong.');
    }
}



</script>
```

this is how i have called this javascript from server side on page load.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript([GetType](), ClientID, " HandleIT();", True)
```

below is the carousel JS

```javascript
var count = 0; 
var baseSpeed = 0.05; 
var radiusX = 190; 
var radiusY = 40; 
var centerX = 300; 
var centerY = 190;
var speed = 0.3;
var imageDivs = '';
var numberOfElements = 0;
var carousel = '';
var speedTest = '';


window.addEvent('domready', function(){

    carousel = $('carousel');
    speedTest = $('speedTest');

    imageDivs = carousel.getElementsByTagName("div"); 
    numberOfElements = imageDivs.length; 

    setInterval('startCarousel()',40);

    carousel.addEvent('mousemove', onMouseMove.bindWithEvent( carousel ));

});

function onMouseMove( evt ) {

    tempX = evt.client.x;
    speed = (tempX - centerX) / 2500;

}

function startCarousel(){

    for(i=0; i < numberOfElements; i++){

        angle = i * ( Math.PI * 2 ) / numberOfElements;

        imageDivsStyle = imageDivs[ i ].style; 
        imageDivsStyle.position='absolute'; 

        posX = ( Math.sin( count * ( baseSpeed * speed ) + angle )* radiusX + centerX );
        posY = ( Math.cos( count * ( baseSpeed * speed ) + angle )* radiusY + centerY );


        imageDivsStyle.left = posX+"px"; 
        imageDivsStyle.top = posY+"px"

        imageDivWidth = posY/3;
        imageDivZIndex = Math.round(imageDivWidth)+100;

        imageDivsStyle.width = imageDivWidth+'px';
        imageDivsStyle.zIndex = imageDivZIndex;

        angle += speed;

    }

    count++
}
```

Also i am using the moottools JS

Can any one please help. I have checked it in IE. it is not showing any error of Javascript. But it not loads. It only shows a big icon of first item (in both chrome and IE). And after reload it works in chrome not in IE.

Comment: this is coded in asp.net. Is it possible to recreate it on fiddle?

Comment: Try this: http://dotnetfiddle.net/

Comment: is `PageMethods.GetCarousel(onSucess, onError);` async? is so, it should be the one starting the carousel after it sets the html, not independently.

Comment: hi @Dimitar, asunc is not supported in IE9 and its previous versions. I have added it like( PageMethods.GetCarousel(onSucess, onError); async ) but it is not working in chrome and in IE8 showing error as it is not supported below IE10

Comment: hi Sergio, if you not mind i can send you files on your private id?